# Can Compiler/Resharper detect enums with same underlying value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, resharper, compiler-warnings

In our project we are using a lot of enumerations in C#. The number of enumerations grow as the project grows as well. As we persist some to DB, we always set underlying base values for them.

Assume the following code:

```
enum Weekdays
{
    Mon = 1,
    Tue = 2,
    Wen = 3,
    Thu = 4,
    Fri = 5,
    Sat = 6,
    Sun = 6,
}
```

You can see that Sunday is copy pasted and I want to define this as an error. If we use resharper it detects the issue when we use them in a switch statement.

However I would like to be able to detect this earlier in the definition for the enum itself (forcing enum to not have any 2 enums with same underlying value). This would help for cases where we define the enum, persist to the database and later on implement the code for the switches.

Is there any feasible way to include this check on Visual Studio or Resharper (I have VS 2013 Ultimate)?

Comment: not answer but you can just set `Mon = 1`  and the compiler by default set the next enum values in order. so they become 2,3,4,... (you dont need to set values for all)

Comment: Also, I assume this is just an example. But just in case it isn't - don't do what you just did, use the [`System.DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enum.

Comment: @Gediminas Your assumption is right - I just wanted to put it as an example.

Comment: @Kazem - it would not work, think about the case where for any reason you forget and remove one of the enums in the middle from the code (or some other developer who is not aware of this does) - you break the whole synchronization between database and the software itself.